# Condition Formatting error

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I am unable use condition formatting using the code below, I don't know were  I am going wrong here:

```
Sub condition_formatting_ms_sheet_test()

Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("ms").Activate

Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("ms").Range("a1:CZ1000").FormatConditions.Delete

Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("ms").Range("AG:AG").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=2"
Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("ms").Range("AG:AG").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=3"
Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("ms").Range("AG:AG").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=4"
Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("ms").Range("AG:AG").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=5"
Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("ms").Range("AG:AG").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=6"
Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("ms").Range("AG:AG").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=7"

Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("ms").Range("AG:AG").FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("ms").Range("AG:AG").FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("ms").Range("AG:AG").FormatConditions(3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 200, 200)
Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("ms").Range("AG:AG").FormatConditions(4).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 0)
Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("ms").Range("AG:AG").FormatConditions(5).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 100, 100)
Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("ms").Range("AG:AG").FormatConditions(6).Interior.Color = RGB(100, 0, 100)

Application.Workbooks(file_name).Worksheets("ms").Range("AG:AG").Font.Bold = True


End Sub
```

Comment: what is your exact problem? not working? not as expected? any error message - where and what? have you tried debugging?

Comment: its not working as expected for some reason . cell color remains the same . i am not getting any error message on this sir.

Comment: what does is mean "not working" - conditional formatting not set after run of the macro, set, but not working? In second case did you open conditional formatting settings and checked rules again?  please be specific as without understanding the question we can't help. Also please don't answer in comments but edit your question.

Comment: This code as posted cannot possibly run with no error because `file_name` has no value. Please post the rest of your code.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me.

```
Option Explicit

Sub condition_formatting_ms_sheet_test()



ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:Z").FormatConditions.Delete

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=2"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=3"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=4"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=5"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=6"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=7"

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions(3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 200, 200)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions(4).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 0)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions(5).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 100, 100)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions(6).Interior.Color = RGB(100, 0, 100)

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Font.Bold = True


End Sub
```

Maybe you should do it like this -

```
Option Explicit

Sub condition_formatting_ms_sheet_test()
Dim DesiredWB As Workbook
Set DesiredWB = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=file_name)



DesiredWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:Z").FormatConditions.Delete

DesiredWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=2"
DesiredWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=3"
DesiredWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=4"
DesiredWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=5"
DesiredWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=6"
DesiredWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, Formula1:="=7"

DesiredWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
DesiredWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
DesiredWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions(3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 200, 200)
DesiredWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions(4).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 0)
DesiredWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions(5).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 100, 100)
DesiredWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").FormatConditions(6).Interior.Color = RGB(100, 0, 100)

DesiredWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Font.Bold = True


End Sub
```